# pytesseract | Difference between image_to_string and image_to_boxes

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm using `pytesseract` to perform OCR. My application only perform OCR on PNGs with a specific font, so I'm in the process of training tesseract to that specific font.

Consider the following test image (`test_1.png`):

[image]

This code:

```
img = Image.open('test_1.png')
pytesseract.image_to_string(image=img)
```

will produce this result:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetm
elit. Fusce tcmpus dignissim diam. Null
dapibus cu, dignissim nec, vulputate egt
Curabitur aliquam, augue eget posuere z
lacus varius augue, sit amet lacinia uma
```

I want to produce a .box file so I can train tesseract. 
I'm using the following code to do that (exactly the same image):

```
boxes = pytesseract.image_to_boxes(image=img)
```

This produces a **completely different result:**

[image]

**Question:** Why is there such a big difference between the results from `image_to_text` and `image_to_boxes`?

Comment: Image to boxes does what it says it does. If there's a big difference, it might be the image to boxes engine isn't as accurate as the simple image to text engine.

Answer (score 0):

It has been more than 4 years from the question asked but I just found a good solution to this. Hope this will help someone in the future.
 
After looking at the source code of pytesseract I noticed that the `image_to_boxes` and `image_to_string` functions do produce different output as you said. The original code for `image_to_boxes` uses `batch.nochop` in its config:

```
# Source code 
def image_to_boxes(
    image,
    lang=None,
    config='',
    nice=0,
    output_type=Output.STRING,
    timeout=0,
):
    """
    Returns string containing recognized characters and their box boundaries
    """
    config = f'{config.strip()} batch.nochop makebox'
    args = [image, 'box', lang, config, nice, timeout]

    return {
        Output.BYTES: lambda: run_and_get_output(*(args + [True])),
        Output.DICT: lambda: file_to_dict(
            f'char left bottom right top page\n{run_and_get_output(*args)}',
            ' ',
            0,
        ),
        Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
    }[output_type]()
```

which this config doesn't appear in the `image_to_string` function. In fact `image_to_string` doesn't seem to use any config at all. I propose the following monkey patching that you can include in your script since modify source code might not be desirable for you (you might want to ship your code elsewhere where you are unable to modify the source code)

In your own script and assuming you don't need the `DICT` functionality.

```
# Modification
from pytesseract import Output, run_and_get_output

def image_to_boxes_keep_same(
    image,
    lang=None,
    config='',
    nice=0,
    output_type=Output.STRING,
    timeout=0,
):
    """
    Returns string containing recognized characters and their box boundaries
    """
    config = f'{config.strip()} makebox'
    args = [image, 'box', lang, config, nice, timeout]

    return {
        Output.BYTES: lambda: run_and_get_output(*(args + [True])),
        Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
    }[output_type]()
```

It should work perfectly.

Note that the original boxes implementation using `batch.nochop` is probably(!) for merging overlapping boxes, I can see why the dev include this, but overlapping boxes is fine for me as long as the result matches with `image_to_string`. Why the dev didn't clarify the use of `batch.nochop` is a thing I'm not sure about.